# Trying to make a character controller but key input gets messed up if I button mash

Tags: javascript

I am very new to this kind of javascript like I just started messing around with how to draw stuff on the canvas a few days ago so I might be doing this completely inefficiently or my code may be very bad. I am trying to make a character controller, so w = go up, d = go right, a = go left, s = go down. I had some problems where a keyup function would be called for "D" (so i set all the speeds to 0), and even though my finger would be pressing down the "A" key it would still stop the game character. I generally fixed all of this with if statements and keeping a variable for the direction the character is moving in. However, if I spam "a' and "d", it usually starts to move left (sometimes right) all the time without any input.

I console logged the left, right, etc, variables to see if maybe one of them was not being set to false on a keyup. I was correct in thinking this, but if I do the same thing slowly, the program works fine and the character will ultimately go in the direction of whatever the current key that is down is.

```
var myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
  myGameArea.start();
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
};

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  };
  this.newPos = function() {
    this.y += this.speedY;
    this.x += this.speedX;
  };
}

function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
}

function moveup() {
  myGamePiece.speedY = -3;
}

function movedown() {
  myGamePiece.speedY = 3;
}

function moveright() {
  myGamePiece.speedX = 3;
}

function moveleft() {
  myGamePiece.speedX = -3;
}

function stop() {
  myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
  myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
}

var right = false;
var left = false;
var up = false;
var down = false;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 87 || e.which == 119) {
    up = true;
    moveup();
  } else if (e.which == 83 || e.which == 115) {
    down = true;
    movedown();
  } else if (e.which == 68 || e.which == 100) {
    right = true;
    console.log("d: " + right);
    moveright();
  } else if (e.which == 65 || e.which == 97) {
    left = true;
    console.log("a: " + left);
    moveleft();
  }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  //up
  if (e.which == 87 || e.which == 119) {
    if (myGamePiece.speedY < 0) {
      up = false;
      stop();
    }
  }
  //down
  else if (e.which == 83 || e.which == 115) {
    if (myGamePiece.speedY > 0) {
      down = false;
      stop();
    }
  }
  //right
  else if (e.which == 68 || e.which == 100) {
    if (myGamePiece.speedX > 0) {
      right = false;
      stop();
      console.log("d: " + right);
      if (left == true) {
        moveleft();
      }
    }
  }
  //left
  else if (e.which == 65 || e.which == 97) {
    if (myGamePiece.speedX < 0) {
      left = false;
      stop();
      console.log("a: " + left);
      if (right == true) {
        moveright();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

My goal here is that I wanted to accomplish this in a way that I actually knew what I was doing, and not just copying code that was better. If there is a better approach to anything I'm trying to do in this I would be happy to hear it. 
Thank you!

This is with the debounce

```
var debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
            var timeout;
            return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) {
                func.apply(context, args);
            }
        };
        if (immediate && !timeout) {
            func.apply(context, args);
        }

        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    };
};


        $(document).keydown(debounce(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 87 || e.which == 119) {
                up = true;
                moveup();
            }
            else if((e.which == 83 || e.which == 115)) {
                down = true;
                movedown();
            }  
            else if((e.which == 68 || e.which == 100)) {
                right = true;
                console.log("d: " + right);
                moveright();
            }  
            else if((e.which == 65 || e.which == 97)) {
                left = true;
                console.log("a: " + left);
                moveleft();
            }  
        }, 100));

        $(document).keyup(debounce(function(e) {
            //up
            if(e.which == 87 || e.which == 119) {
                if (myGamePiece.speedY < 0)
                    {
                        up = false;
                        stop();  
                    }
            }
            //down
            else if((e.which == 83 || e.which == 115)) {
                if (myGamePiece.speedY > 0)
                    {
                        down = false;
                        stop();  
                    }
            } 
            //right
            else if((e.which == 68 || e.which == 100)) {
                if (myGamePiece.speedX > 0)
                    {
                        right = false;
                        stop();  
                        console.log("d: " + right);
                        if (left == true) {
                            moveleft();
                        }
                    }
            }  
            //left
            else if((e.which == 65 || e.which == 97)) {
                if (myGamePiece.speedX < 0)
                    {
                        left = false;
                        stop();  
                        console.log("a: " + left);
                        if (right == true) {
                            moveright();
                        }
                    }
            }  
        }, 100));
```

Comment: You could use a debounce as shown in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538344/asynchronous-keyup-events-how-to-short-circuit-sequential-keyup-events-for-speed)

Comment: I believe I implemented it correctly, I can set the value at the end to a higher number and it will delay the input. On a very high number, it fixes the problem, but there is a large delay that makes it basically unplayable. I put the value at 100, and it is a little bit too much delay, but the problem persists. Ill include some of my new code after my existing code. I don't totally understand how the debounce works yet so I could have very well missed something obvious.

Comment: @SpencerBellucci here's an interactive explanation of debounce (along with immediate and throttle) https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Comment: Ok, ill check it out. Thank you!

Comment: *update I found out if I do a certain key combo it does the same thing so I looked through my if statements and I was setting the keys to false after an if statement that would only be true if it was going a certain direction. I was able to fix the problem but I think ill still look into debounce just to avoid any problems.